# VB.Net and SQL Command Unhandled Exception

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlcmd

I am building a simple program for bulk load  into SQL. However I cannot figure out this error. The raw code is below, then the translated code without the textbox references.

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles insert.Click

    Dim SQLCONN As New SqlConnection
    Dim SQLCMD As New SqlCommand
    SQLCONN = New SqlConnection("Server=" + server.Text + ";Database=" + database.Text + ";Integrated security=True")
    SQLCONN.Open()
    SQLCMD = New SqlCommand("BULK INSERT " + table.Text +
        " FROM " + path.Text +
        "  With (FIRSTROW = '" + firstrow.Text + "',
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '" + seperator.Text + "',
            ROWTERMINATOR= '\n');", SQLCONN)
    SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SQLCONN.Close()

End Sub
```

Here is what the SQL portion would translate to

```
SQLCMD = New SqlCommand("BULK INSERT test1
         FROM  'C:\Program Files\Servers\FFA\csgo\maplist.txt'
          With (FIRSTROW = '2',
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
            ROWTERMINATOR= '\n')";, SQLCONN)
```

Here is the error I get:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'C:'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

Can anyone help me figure out why this is erroring out?

Comment: That should end up as`FIRSTROW = 2`, i.e. without the quotes. Also, the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the double quote from your `FIRSTROW` value

```
SQLCMD = New SqlCommand("BULK INSERT test1
         FROM  'C:\Program Files\Servers\FFA\csgo\maplist.txt'
          With (FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = ' ',
            ROWTERMINATOR= '\n')";, SQLCONN)
```

Your class will be like as follow

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles insert.Click

    Dim SQLCONN As New SqlConnection
    Dim SQLCMD As New SqlCommand
    SQLCONN = New SqlConnection("Server=" + server.Text + ";Database=" + database.Text + ";Integrated security=True")
    SQLCONN.Open()
    SQLCMD = New SqlCommand("BULK INSERT " + table.Text +
        " FROM " + path.Text +
        "  With (FIRSTROW = " + firstrow.Text + ",
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '" + seperator.Text + "',
            ROWTERMINATOR= '\n');", SQLCONN)
    SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SQLCONN.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL has quotes around the filename but the VB version does not (unless the textbox itself contains quotes, but I think it unlikely given the error message):

[image]

Your SQL would be a lot more readable if you use string interpolation and do some preprocessing outside of building the string:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles insert.Click

    Dim SQLCONN As New SqlConnection
    Dim SQLCMD As New SqlCommand
    SQLCONN = New SqlConnection("Server=" + server.Text + ";Database=" + database.Text + ";Integrated security=True")
    SQLCONN.Open()

    Dim p = path.Text.Replace("'","''")
    Dim f = seperator.Text.Replace("'","''")

    SQLCMD = New SqlCommand($"BULK INSERT QUOTENAME({table.Text})
                FROM '{p}'
                WITH (FIRSTROW = {firstrowNumericUpdown.Value}
                FIELDTERMINATOR = '{f}',
                ROWTERMINATOR= '\n')", SQLCONN)
    SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SQLCONN.Close()

End Sub
```

You should also do your utmost to prevent SQL injection with this; you're handing the user several textboxes into which they type something and that could be very dangerous if they decide to write some SQL in the textbox

- Consider using QUOTENAME the table name
- Use a NumericUpDown for your FIRSTROW
- Consider replacing ' with '' on other fields
- Consider limiting the length of the `seperator` textbox to be `MaxLength=1`

If you don't know what SQL Injection Hacking is, take a read of http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, all of your responses helped me quite a bit. I'm deciding to go a different route with project, thanks again!